# Google Prediction API

Tags: google-api, training-data

Does anyone know how to create "training data" for the Google API.

What I'm trying to make is a system that reads a paragraph and picks up the many qualities/features stated and its value.

For example, "The video game was amazing. The background music was nice. The graphics were very high quality. However, the story just wasn't all that great."

And give us: Videogame - Amazing, Background Music - Nice, Graphics - High Quality, Story - Wasn't great.

I've searched this site and haven't seen anything like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Is_video_amazing:1,0
- Is_music_Nice:1,0
- Is_graphic_quality:1,0
- Is_story_great:1,0

so,the trainmodel:

- "1,1,1,0","The video game was amazing. The background music was nice. The graphics were very high quality. However, the story just wasn't all that great"